# Erase firebase instance with app_instance_id from BigQuery

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery

It is possible to erase a customer with InstanceID to comply with GDPR: https://godoc.org/firebase.google.com/go/iid#Client.DeleteInstanceID

However we do not have historical Firebase Instance IDs. BigQuery has a field `app_info.app_instance_id` but this is not a valid instance ID.

Is it possible to erase a customer with `app_instance_id`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An app instance ID identifies (as its name implies) an app instance. It does not identify a specific user. While it is quite common to associate IIDs with users, Firebase has nothing built in for that. This means that, unless you have the data in your database, there is no way to find out the associated IIDs for a user by calling the API.